# Unable to save mongodb record via node script using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here's my js file describing the schema and API's that doesn't work. When I do this via the command line tools it does... The schema is pretty straightforward and I've implemented some simple find commands.

```
'use strict'

var util    = require('util');
var bcrypt  = require('bcrypt');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

var validatePresenceOf = function(value){
  return value && value.length; 
};

var toLower = function(string){
  return string.toLowerCase();
};

var SportsStandings = new Schema({
  'sport' : { type : String, 
              validate : [validatePresenceOf, 'a sport is required'],
              set : toLower
            },
  'league' : { type : String, 
              validate : [validatePresenceOf, 'a league is required'],
              set : toLower
            },
  'division' : { type : String, 
              validate : [validatePresenceOf, 'a division is required'],
              set : toLower
            },
  'teamName' : { type : String, 
              validate : [validatePresenceOf, 'a teamName is required'],
              set : toLower
            },
   'wins' : { type : Number, min: 0, 
              validate : [validatePresenceOf, 'wins is required'],
            },
   'losses' : { type : Number, min: 0, 
              validate : [validatePresenceOf, 'losses is required'],
            }
});

SportsStandings.statics.findTeamRecord = function(sport, league, 
                                                  division, teamName,
                                              cb) {
  return  this.find({'sport' : sport, 'league' : league, 
                     'division' : division, 'teamName': teamName}, cb);
};

SportsStandings.statics.findBySport = function(sport, cb) {
  return  this.find({'sport' : sport}, cb);
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('SportsStanding' , SportsStandings);
```

---

and here's the simple node script that instantiates an object exported above and tries to do the save command on the Model.....

```
'use strict'

var util = require('util');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mydb');
var SportsStanding  = require('../schemas/SportsStandings');

var record = new SportsStanding({ 
          'sport' : 'mlb',
          'league' : 'AL',
          'divison' : 'east',
          'teamName' : 'New York Yankees',
          'wins' : 10,
          'losses' : 1});

record.save(function(err) {
    console.log('error: ' + err);
    SportsStandings.find().all(function(arr) {
    console.log(arr); 
    console.log('length='+arr.length);
    });
});

process.exit();
```

Comment: What error are you seeing? When you say it doesn't work, is there some output that can help us diagnose the problem?

Comment: Nothing happens. I run the program using node on the command line: node sportsStandings.js and there's no error and nothing committed to the database so far as I can tell using the mongo command line tools. If I use the mongo command line to do db.sportsStandings.insert(....) it works....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remember that when programming with node.js you have to be very careful with the event-driven programming style. The problem with your code appears to be that you're calling `process.exit()` at the outer execution level. When you call `record.save(...)` it will return control to that outer execution level immediately and not allow the save to execute or any of the code in the save's callback.

To solve this you'll want to move your `process.exit()` to the end of your inner-most callback function and then you should see the results you're expecting.

Running your example I found a couple of other typos and mistakes you'll need to correct. Check the spelling of your `SportStanding(s)` model variable and make sure it matches everywhere. Also, the `find()` on your model needs a callback and it returns all of the records in your database (as the second parameter - an error flag is the first) so there is no need for the chained `all()` call. What you want for your save function should end up looking like:

```
record.save(function(err) {
  console.log('error: ' + err);
  SportsStandings.find(function(err, arr) {
      console.log(arr);
      console.log('length='+arr.length);
      process.exit();
  });
});
```